# How do you use a variable as a dot notation address?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, syntax

I have this problem where it needs a dot notation address but I need part of it to be changeable. It does not accept variable content though and it thinks the variable name is part of the address.

```
for item in sorted(vars(self.buttons)):
        vars(self.rbuttons)[item] = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text=vars(self.buttons)[item][0], width=15, command=lambda: self.addCost(vars(self.buttons)[item][1])
        vars(self.rbuttons)[item].grid(column=self.colCount,row=self.rowCount,sticky=(W,E))
```

The problem is in `self.addCost(vars(self.buttons)[item][1])`.
I need the `arg` to say: `self.buttons.item_value[1]`

How you do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr) or [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#setattr) functions:

```
class M:
     def __init__(self):
             self.moo = 'default'

m = M()
print(getattr(m, 'moo')) # 'default'
setattr(m, 'moo', 'changed')
print(getattr(m, 'moo')) # 'changed'
```

Comment: The cortect usage for your example would be `getattr(m, 'moo')`.

Comment: Thanks @Klaus D., my Python is bit rusty these days.